# Extarct data using pattern matching in java

Tags: java, regex, matching

I have a requriement in Java to extarct data from the big string using `Pattern.compile()`.

INPUT STRING :

```
[{"KEY1" :"VALUE1","KEY2" :"VALUE2","KEY3" :"VALUE3","KEY4" :"VALUE4"},{"KEY1" :"VALUE5","KEY2" :"VALUE6","KEY3" :"VALUE7","KEY4" :"VALUE8"}]
```

OUTPUT :
set of 2 string

```
first :  {"KEY1" :"VALUE1","KEY2" :"VALUE2","KEY3" :"VALUE3","KEY4" :"VALUE4"}
second : {"KEY1" :"VALUE5","KEY2" :"VALUE6","KEY3" :"VALUE7","KEY4" :"VALUE8"}
```

I am trying below code :

```
     ArrayList<String> token_data = new ArrayList<String>();

     String myString = "[{"KEY1" :"VALUE1","KEY2" :"VALUE2","KEY3" :"VALUE3","KEY4" :"VALUE4"},{"KEY1" :"VALUE5","KEY2" :"VALUE6","KEY3" :"VALUE7","KEY4" :"VALUE8"}]"
        System.out.println(myString);
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
        Matcher m = p1.matcher(myString);

        while(m.find())
        {

            System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
            //m.group(1);
            token_data.add(m.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: @solomkinmv
above code gives o/p as below:
KEY1
VALUE1
KEY2
VALUE2
.
.
.
likewise till VALUE8

Comment: @YCF_L thanks for editing the question properly

Comment: so you want to devise the result 4 by 4?

Comment: I think you mean regular expressions, not design patterns (as your tag says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, here is the regex: `{(.*)}`. Note, that you need to mark it as ungreedy.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/x6ZX56/2

Result:

**1**

Full match: `{"KEY1" :"VALUE1","KEY2" :"VALUE2","KEY3" :"VALUE3","KEY4" :"VALUE4"}`

Group 1: `"KEY1" :"VALUE1","KEY2" :"VALUE2","KEY3" :"VALUE3","KEY4" :"VALUE4"`

**2**

Full match: `{"KEY1" :"VALUE5","KEY2" :"VALUE6","KEY3" :"VALUE7","KEY4" :"VALUE8"}`

Group 1: `"KEY1" :"VALUE5","KEY2" :"VALUE6","KEY3" :"VALUE7","KEY4" :"VALUE8"`

Java example:

```
    String input = "[{\"KEY1\" :\"VALUE1\",\"KEY2\" :\"VALUE2\",\"KEY3\" :\"VALUE3\",\"KEY4\" :\"VALUE4\"},{\"KEY1\" :\"VALUE5\",\"KEY2\" :\"VALUE6\",\"KEY3\" :\"VALUE7\",\"KEY4\" :\"VALUE8\"}]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)}");

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Note, that I used escaping characters for the input string.

Comment: this is totally correct i really don't notice the `{}` good hint have my UV :)

Comment: Bingooo!!!! @solomkinmv , it working perfectly.Thanks a lot fro the help.Full marks to your code.